# Finding duplicate files in Unix by content

Tags: shell, unix

How to find the list of duplicate files recursively by content instead of file name

Comment: https://github.com/adrianlopezroche/fdupes

Comment: Compute a hash for each of the files, then check for collisions.

Comment: A good start: `find . -type f -exec md5sum {} \;  | sort`

Comment: `grep -rH 'the contents to find' | cut -d : -f1 | uniq | { while read -r line; do md5sum "$line"; done; }`

Answer (score 0):

find . -type f -exec basename {} \; | sed 's/(.*)..*/\1/' | sort | uniq -c | grep -v "^[ \t]*1 "

This will search the duplicate files with the folders.